# ARM, which of the 16 registers is the CPSR?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers

I am a bit confused right now, the table below shows the ARM registers available to the programmer as far as I know:

```
| Register Name    | Register Number | Usage                |
| ---------------- | --------------- | -------------------- |
| r0 - r10         | 0 - 10          | General Purpose      |
| r11 or fp        | 11              | Frame Pointer        |
| r12 or ip        | 12              | Intraprocess scratch |
| r13 or sp        | 13              | Stack Pointer        |
| r14 or lr        | 14              | Link Register        |
| r15 or pc        | 15              | Program Counter      |
```

But there is also the CPSR adressed for example by the `TST` instruction.
So my question is, which of the 16 registers is the CPSR?

Comment: Have yo u had a look at the ARM Architecture references manual for the given ARM instruction set version?

Comment: note that all of them are considered general purpose, this chart you have is specific to a calling convention which has nothing whatsoever to do with the processor design. r13, r14 and r15 are connected to certain instructions in a way that the others are not (well, depends on the core with respect to r13).  but there is also banking in some of the cores which is also in the arm arm...(multiplying the number of registers further there are 30 something of them if not more).

Comment: @marko how could I find the right manual for my instruction set (maybe with a let me google that for you)?

Answer (score 2):

None of them.  This isn't a complete list of *all* the machine's registers, only of the **general-purpose registers** (`r0-r14`) and the program counter.  The machine has many more registers that are not general purpose, and the CPSR is one of them.  Indeed, in my copy of the armv8 Architecture Reference Manual, the CPSR is explicitly called a "special-purpose" register.